# simple JNI example Android

Tags: android, linux, java-native-interface, classpath

I am trying to create a simple Android-JNI example, but I am getting error while trying to generate the header files.
Link I am following is :

http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/android_ndk.html

I am getting error in 2nd step :

```
javah -classpath ../../bin/classes;<ANDROID_SDK_HOME>\platforms\android-<xx>\android.jar 
 -o HelloJNI.h com.mytest.JNIActivity
```

I modified the command as per my usecase mentioned below : 
Error :

```
 [SimpleJni]#javah -classpath ./bin/classes;/home/xxxxxx/Documents/8.7.14ADT/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702/sdk/platforms/android-18/android.jar com.example.simplejni.JNIActivity
Error: no classes specified
bash: /home/xxxxxx/Documents/8.7.14ADT/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702/sdk/platforms/android-18/android.jar: cannot execute binary file
```

I am not able to understand the issue. I checked the permission for the jar file as well and I set it to 755.
What else I am supposed to do? Where I am doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
javah -classpath ../../bin/classes/ -bootclasspath /home/xxxxxx/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-23/android.jar -o HelloJNI.h com.mytest.JNIActivity
```